# How to match the pin of this IC in LTspice?

Tags: voltage, transistors, power, current, resistors

[image]

[image]

Refering to the datasheet [here](https://www.ti.com/lit/ds/symlink/cd4017b.pdf), I find it hard to predict the names of the pins because the names are different for these 2 pictures. Is C0 the same as CE, and should CLK_INH be left floating/unconnected, because I don't see the LTSPICE CLK_INH pin on the datasheet?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

- \$CO\$ stands for carry-out
- \$C\$ stands for "clock" or \$CLK\$
- \$\overline{CLK\text{_}INH}\$ stands for clock inhibit (when low) or, more simply CE (clock enable)

[image]

Don't leave any input\$^1\$ pins unconnected. Always connect to either logic 1 or 0 unless the data sheets says otherwise.

\$^1\$ corrected by adding the word "input".

Comment: Don't leave any INPUT pins unconnected.  Unconnected output pins are OK.  Connecting unused output pins to power or ground would be a Bad Thing.

Comment: @PeterBennett yes, absolutely correct. I shall amend.

Comment: @Andyaka, hi sir, thank you for answering. Just one question, if I use 2 CD4017 and I give the same clock signal to both of them (connect to same node) , will the leds rain simultaneously to each other without going out of phase from each other? SO, these chips have phase-locking machanism.

Comment: @PeterBennett, hi sir, thank you for answering. Just one question, if I use 2 CD4017 and I give the same clock signal to both of them (connect to same node) , will the leds rain simultaneously to each other without going out of phase from each other? SO, these chips have phase-locking machanism.

Comment: @jessicasmith what LEDs do you refer to? If both 4017s are un-reset together than they should remain in sync. The CLK signal keeps them in sync. But, beware of the reset pin; it isn't synchronous and, on odd occasions, the two devices may not be restored synchronously.